# Produto escalar

Tags: pandas, numpy

Objetivo: Fazer um neurônio usando a carga de pesos e inputs a partir de um xlsx

O produto escalar foi calculado de diversas formas como exercício, mas quando tento usar o dot dá erro.

os input:

Entrada
-1,00
7,00
5,00

os pesos:

Pesos
0,80
0,10
0,00

estão em um arquivo chamado neural.xlsx

o código:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt
import sys
import csv
import os
import subprocess
import locale
import decimal
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timezone , date, timedelta
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import unicodedata
import pandas as pd

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
21/09/2018 

@author:Guido D'Angelo
"""
'''----------------------------------------------------------------------
Carrega pesos e inputs
----------------------------------------------------------------------
'''
Nome_arquivo=input(" entre com o nome do arquivo de inputs e pesos")
TEMP={"Mult":[]}
INPUTS=pd.read_excel(Nome_arquivo, sheet_name="INPUTS")
WEIGHTS=pd.read_excel(Nome_arquivo, sheet_name="Weight")

'''
calcula o produto escalar trabalando com array
'''
print("produto Escalar com values")
INPUTS1=INPUTS.values
WEIGHTS1=WEIGHTS.values
print(INPUTS1)
print(WEIGHTS1)
print("Escalar ",sum(INPUTS1*WEIGHTS1))

print("________________________________")



'''
Calcula o produto escalar com laço for
'''
print("Escalar com laço for")
SOMA=0.0
for i in range(0,len(INPUTS)):
               SOMA+=INPUTS.loc[i,'Entrada']*WEIGHTS.loc[i,'Pesos']

print("Escalar ",SOMA)
'''
Calcula com dot
'''
print("Escalar ",INPUTS1.dot(WEIGHTS))
```

como resultado tenho:
 entre com o nome do arquivo de inputs e pesosneural.xlsx

> produto Escalar com values
>   [[-1]
>    [ 7]
>    [ 5]]
>   [[0.8]
>    [0.1]
>    [0. ]]
>   Escalar  [-0.1]
>
> ---
>
> Escalar com laço for
>   Escalar  -0.09999999999999998
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>    File "C:\Users\g0024041\Documents\Python\Redes Neurais\perceptron1.py", line 56, in <module>
>      print("Escalar ",INPUTS1.dot(WEIGHTS))
>   ValueError: shapes (3,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

está claro que quando uso o values, em vez de ter um shape de 3 tenho o shape de 3,1
Como então transformar um dataframe (já que usei pd.read_excel) em um np.array?
Como usar o dot neste caso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa. Isso é um erro muito comum. na verdade o erro não é de programação mas sim na matemática.
Quando multiplicamos dois vetores temos que transpor o segundo.

logo basta substituir(acrescentar.):

```
print("Escalar ",INPUTS1.dot(WEIGHTS))
```

por

```
print("Escalar ",INPUTS1.dot(WEIGHTS.T))
```

Espero ter ajudado